# Opacity adopted to child elements

Tags: css, opacity

I have the following overlay and need to have the background fade but the text and button to be full opacity of 1. I have attempted to move the styling around seeing if that would fix it. I have viewed other questions that have given answers that do not give the desired effects. Any suggestions?

```
<div id="myNav" class="overlay" style="z-index:0.1; background: rgb(26, 35, 126) ; opacity: 0.6;">
<div class="w3-container w3-padding-32" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;
text-align: center;">
<h1 style="color: black;">Thank you for visiting our website!</h1>
<button>Continue to our website</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the `opacity` in the parent div `overlay` and added the opacity just in the background style, you can use `rgba` so you can add opacity at the fourth place value, the format is like this `background: rgba(26, 35, 126, 0.6)`, see below html

HTML

```
<div id="myNav" class="overlay" style="z-index:0.1;background: rgba(26, 35, 126, 0.6);">
<div class="w3-container w3-padding-32" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;
text-align: center;">
<h1 style="color: black;">Thank you for visiting our website!</h1>
<button>Continue to our website</button>
</div>
</div>
```